# Write sqlite3 in-memory database into file using clsql

Tags: sqlite, common-lisp, clsql

As the question indicates. I created an in-memory database using `":memory:"` and `clsql:with-database` to increase write/insert-query performance. But in the end I do want to have a permanent copy of the filled database on my hard drive.

It should look something like this:

```
(clsql:with-database (db (":memory:") :database-type :sqlite3)
  ;;entering db-scheme
  ;;entering a bunch of data
  (magically-write-database-to-file db file-path))
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not care about data consistency before the database creation has finished, just use a normal database file and configure it to disable [transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) and [disk synchronization](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous):

```
(execute-command "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF")
(execute-command "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF")
```

Comment: that significantly increased the write/insert speed. I'd be curious about an explanation though.

Comment: `synchronous` ensures that data has been written to disk when the transaction completes. The journal is needed to roll back a failed or interrupted transaction. Without these, interrupting or aborting any database write will leave you with a corrupted database.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you just need to create the tables with `create-view-from-class`, then call `update-records-from-instance` on your objects.

I am not sure, though, whether the creation of an explicit in-memory database first really makes sense.  You could just create a collection of objects first, then put them into the database with `update-records-from-instance` in one go.  The "view classes" of CLSQL are really just ordinary classes with some information about how to save/load them.  There is no magic going on when you just change the objects without saving.